# How to notify everyone in a Trello board?

Tags: trello, notifications

Is there a way to "@ spam" the entire Trello board, similar to @room on Slack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you elaborate what you mean by *Room*?

If by that you mean *Board* then you can use **@board** to notify everyone in the board.

Comment: Sorry, I did mean board (updated the question). Was taking the Slack analogy too literally! @board is good, thanks.